# How can I make my monitor run at it's native resolution under Kubuntu 9.10?

Tags: ubuntu, resolution, kubuntu, x-windows, intel-graphics

I have installed Kubuntu 9.10 afresh on an HP desktop computer with a Samsung SyncMaster 2243 and Intel integrated graphics card. The screen resolution is fixed on `1280x1024` instead of the native `1680x1050`, which makes my eyes bleed.

```
$ lspci -k |grep "VGA" -A2
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31 
             Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 10)
        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915
```

and my xorg.conf:

```
/etc/X11$ cat xorg.conf
Section "Device"
        Identifier      "Configured Video Device"
        Driver          "vesa"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier      "Configured Monitor"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier      "Default Screen"
        Monitor         "Configured Monitor"
        Device          "Configured Video Device"
EndSection
```

Any ideas how to make this driver work? I found no working solutions on Google searches.

Thanks,

Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was told in [a thread I started in an Israeli Linux fan site](http://whatsup.org.il/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&p=339094#339094) ([translation to English](http://translate.google.com/translate?js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=1&eotf=1&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwhatsup.org.il%2Findex.php%3Fname%3DPNphpBB2%26file%3Dviewtopic%26p%3D339094%23339094&sl=iw&tl=en)), to switch `"vesa"` to `"intel"` in `xorg.conf` - and it works!

I thought Ubuntu was over this kind of configurations already.